# when to stop when number is not a happy number

Tags: python, algorithm

A happy number is defined by the following process. Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1.

But when number is not a happy number it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.

i have coded happy number problem in python but the problem is when a number is not happy , then how could i stop the iterating cycle. since it will not end with 1 and will keep on repeating itself.

```
def happynumber(number):

while(number!=1):
    numberstr = str(number) #converting a number to string
    index=0 
    sum=0
    while(index!=len(numberstr)):
        sum = sum + int(numberstr[index])*int(numberstr[index])
        index = index+1
    print sum

    number = sum
return number
```

Comment: Could you show us what you did?

Comment: You have to think of a way to detect the cycle and break it. That should be enough of a hint for homework. ;)

Comment: Is there a limit to how long the sequence will go before it either repeats or gets to 1? (I would guess not, in which case it's a hard problem.)

Comment: @AndrewJaffe, I expect there's a definite limit. There's no way the sequence can grow forever - once you get past a certain size, the sum of squares of digits of x is always smaller than x itself. So for any starting number, the sequence will surely start to loop after a finite number of steps.

Comment: yes it does repeat itself but it would be different for different number

Comment: Tip: a "happy" step can be written more compactly as `new = sum(int(d)**2 for d in str(old))`.  Python has very nice iteration abilities, and usually when you're using a while loop with an index you're doing more work than you need to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can detect unhappy numbers with a constant amount of memory. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#10-happy_numbers), for any positive integer starting point, the sequence will terminate at one, or loop forever at `4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4`. Since no other loops exist, it is easy to test for unhappiness.

```
def isHappy(x):
    while True:
        if x == 1:
            return True
        if x == 4:
            return False
        x = nextNumberInSequence(x)
```

Answer (score 8):

You would have to keep a record of all the numbers you have produced so far in the sequence, and if one of them comes up a second time you know you have a loop which will never reach 1. A [set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) is probably a good choice for a place to store the numbers.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for teaching purposes because it's the most general, and the least dependent upon particular properties of happy numbers.

Comment: @PierreGM: if at step `i` you get a power of 10 times the value at step `j`, then step `i+1` will be equal to step `j+1`, which is another number from earlier in the sequence. So there's no need to catch that case specially, you can just wait one more step and find the cycle then.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the current number has more than 3 digits, it's value decreases in the next iteration. When the number has 3 digits, the maximum value it can take in the next iteration is 3*81 <= 250. So use an array of size 250 and record all the numbers in the sequence that are less than 250. You can then easily detect if you have a duplicate.

Comment: Python's integer type is arbitrary-precision.

Comment: @DSM Thanks! I didn't know that. Fixed my answer to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return true , if given number is happy number or else it will return false. We are using set here to avoid infinite loop situation.

Input: 19

Output: true

Explanation:

1*1 + 9*9 = 82

8*8 + 2*2 = 68

6*6 + 8*8 = 100

1*1 + 0*0 + 0*0 = 1

```
     public static boolean isHappy(int n) {

          Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();

          while(n != 1) {
            int current = n;
            int sum = 0;
            while(current != 0) {
                sum += (current % 10) * (current % 10);
                current /= 10;
            }

            if(seen.contains(sum)) {
                return false;
            }

            seen.add(sum);
            n = sum;
        }

        return true;

    }
```