# My code does not take care of false condition. Any inputs?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, coding-style

Write an algorithm to determine if a number is "happy".

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Example:

> 19 is a happy number:
>
> 1² + 9² = 82
>
> 8² + 2² = 68
>
> 6² + 8² = 100
>
> 1² + 0² + 0² = 1

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int num) {
        while(num != 1){
            int sum = 0;
            int tempNum = num;

            while(tempNum / 10 > 0) {
                int rem = 0;

                rem = tempNum % 10;
//              System.out.println("rem: "+ rem);
                sum += rem * rem ;
                tempNum = tempNum/10;
//              System.out.println("sum: "+ sum);

//              System.out.println("num: "+ num);
            }
            sum += tempNum * tempNum;
            System.out.println(num);
            num = sum;
        }
        if(num == 1) {
            System.out.println(num);
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false; 
        }
//      break;
    }
    public void main(String args[]){
        int n = 19;
        isHappy(n);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is   *iterates infinitely. How should I modify my code? For any number that is not "happy", it goes to the false condition and the loops*

Comment: You already wrote right ? What is your problem with this code ? Any error ? Exception ?

Comment: StackExchange has a different forum for code review...  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For any number that is not "happy", it goes to the false condition and the loops iterates infinitely. How should I modify my code?

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which unfortunately isn't an option when voting for migration.

Comment: @Jim, Should I repost this again in the link you provided?

Comment: Guys there is a bug. No need to move it  code review.

Comment: @Jim is partly right, partly I'm with Suresh, and nearly voted to close for lack of problem description. However, this is a number theoretical problem, unless you just say "infinity is ca. 1000".

Comment: @Anu please don't do that.

Comment: Not the right language, but the concept is language-invariant: [when to stop when number is not a happy number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12675665/953482)

Comment: @Anu, I voted to migrate before you clarified that you actually have a problem and werent just looking for input / feedback.  Please edit your original post and clarify the actual problem, which is the fact that any input of a non-happy number will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Kevin: that actually makes this a duplicate of the question you cite, because OP didn't ask about the Java specifics but about the algorithmic approach.

Comment: What @Jim said, but consider reading the link that Kevin sent; if you think it is the same question as yours, consider deleting your duplicate.

Comment: @Anu What your debugger telling ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My debugger doesn't show any error but it just runs infinitely for the number that is not "happy"

Comment: @annu025 No. You are returning if it is false.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, Here is what I get on my console:
2
4
16
37
58
89
145
42
20
4

This runs infinitely.